# magento2 - How to add Details field for Custom option in admin?

Tags: magento2

magento2 How to add Details field for Custom option in admin?

How can i add new custom field in custom option admin side in magento 2?
Like magento 1 following link http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options

Thanks..

Comment: Let me know whether you would like to add a new 'Text Field'  like as shown in this screenshot       http://prnt.sc/dwr7fy     ?

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I added Inventory text field for Drop-down custom option.

[image]

Create a module using following code -

**app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyCompany_MyModule" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" />
</config>
```

**app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductOptions\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Product\Options\Price as ProductOptionsPrice;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ActionDelete;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;


class CustomOptions extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions
{
    /**#@+
     * Field values
     * 
     */
    const FIELD_QTY_NAME = 'quantity';

    /**
     * Get config for grid for "select" types
     * 
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getSelectTypeGridConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'addButtonLabel' => __('Add Value'),
                        'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows',
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                        'deleteProperty' => static::FIELD_IS_DELETE,
                        'deleteValue' => '1',
                        'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                'positionProvider' => static::FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME,
                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                'is_collection' => true,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        static::FIELD_TITLE_NAME => $this->getTitleFieldConfig(10),
                        static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME => $this->getPriceFieldConfig(20),
                        static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME => $this->getPriceTypeFieldConfig(30, ['fit' => true]),
                        static::FIELD_SKU_NAME => $this->getSkuFieldConfig(40),
                        static::FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME => $this->getPositionFieldConfig(50),
                        static::FIELD_QTY_NAME => $this->getQtyFieldConfig(55),
                        static::FIELD_IS_DELETE => $this->getIsDeleteFieldConfig(60)
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get config for "Inventory" fields
     * 
     * @param $sortOrder 
     * @param array $options
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getQtyFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = [])
    {
        return array_replace_recursive(
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Inventory'),
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => static::FIELD_QTY_NAME,
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'validation' => [
                                'validate-digits' => true
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            $options
        );
    }
}
```

Add a column with name 'quantity' in Database table 'catalog_product_option_type_value' for storing the inventory value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi this all works, the options is there but the value of attribute is not saved. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hey @Pooja Mistry, do you know how to set this up in such a way that it saves decimals into the database (example: "5.55") instead of rounding to nearest integer?

Comment: Hey, Pooja can you please tell us why its data do not save in database? I have added the column in the database as per your suggestion but still, it's not saved.

Comment: Got the issue. It occurred due to indexing. After indexing its working.

Comment: @Pooja Mistry I used Mageworx Product Options extension and need to get those custom option field in product rest API option ?

Comment: @Pooja Mistry how to get it in front?

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed, and it works perfectly in version 2.3.5-p2 !!

Comment: Its working fine for me