# Add extension attribute in Product Custom Option Value

Tags: magento2, custom-options, extension-attributes

I would like add extension_attribute field in ProductCustomOptionValue entity.

My idea is to use extension_attribute.xml to create news attributes to this entity liking with a new table.

Comment: Hi what is functionality you are going to implement?

Comment: Hi, I want add stock and other operation information. Similar here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147139/magento2-how-to-add-details-field-for-custom-option-in-admin but add field in webapi and without add columns in catalog_product_option_type_value table.

Comment: Any have idea I used Mageworx Product Options extension and need to get those custom option field in product rest API option's value ?